# react native Error after run react-native run-ios --simulator='iPhone 11'

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

Steps:

1. `yarn install`
2. `react-native eject`
3. After I run the command `react-native run-ios --simulator = 'iPhone 11'` and it BUILD SUCCEEDED, but it shows the error "Unhandled JS EXCeption: native module cannot be null".[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxeBV.png)

I don't know what package is caused by an error.

This is my package:

```
"dependencies": {
"@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication": "^2.1.0",
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.13.2",
"@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.0",
"@react-native-community/cameraroll": "^4.0.0",
"@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios": "^4.13.0",
"@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.8.0",
"apisauce": "^1.1.1",
"appcenter": "3.1.1",
"appcenter-analytics": "3.1.1",
"appcenter-crashes": "3.1.1",
"async-storage": "^0.1.0",
"bugsnag-react-native": "^2.23.6",
"format-json": "^1.0.3",
"jest": "^26.4.2",
"lodash": "^4.17.2",
"moment": "^2.18.1",
"prop-types": "^15.7.2",
"querystringify": "0.0.4",
"ramda": "^0.23.0",
"react": "16.8.6",
"react-native": "0.59.0",
"react-native-animatable": "^1.1.0",
"react-native-autocomplete-input": "^3.1.2",
"react-native-base64": "^0.1.0",
"react-native-communications": "^2.2.1",
"react-native-config": "^0.6.1",
"react-native-device-info": "^0.29.1",
"react-native-drawer": "^2.3.0",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "1.4.0",
"react-native-google-signin": "^2.1.1",
"react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.1",
"react-native-maps": "^0.26.1",
"react-native-modal": "^11.5.6",
"react-native-osd-simple-button": "^1.1.0",
"react-native-progress-hud": "^1.0.4",
"react-native-push-notification": "^7.0.0",
"react-native-radio-buttons": "^0.14.0",
"react-native-range-slider": "^0.1.2",
"react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.0",
"react-native-router-flux": "^3.37.0",
"react-native-share": "2.0.0",
"react-native-social-share": "^1.1.0",
"react-native-swiper": "^1.5.11",
"react-native-tab-view": "2.15.2",
"react-native-vector-icons": "7.1.0",
"react-native-webview": "^10.9.2",
"react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.7",
"react-redux": "^5.0.2",
"redux": "^3.6.0",
"redux-persist": "^4.1.0",
"redux-saga": "^0.14.3",
"reduxsauce": "0.4.1",
"rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
"rn-viewpager": "^1.2.4",
"seamless-immutable": "^7.0.1"
```

}

Comment: Did you run `pod install` ?